# Matrix Chain Multiplication + Dynamic Programming + Recurrance Relation

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am going over my review worksheet and was looking for some help with finding the recurrence relation for chained matrix multiplication using dynamic programming.

The problem verbatim:
Consider the optimal parenthesization problem for the chained matrix product `M0M1…Mn - 1` with associated dimension sequence  `(d0, d1, … ,dn)`. Derive the recurrence relation on which the dynamic programming solution for this problem is based, i.e., a recurrence relation for the minimum number mij of multiplications over all parenthesizations of the chained product `MiM1…Mj` .  Don’t forget the initial condition.

I understand the formula for `M[i,j]` `(M[i,j] = M[i,k] + M[k+1,j] + pqr)`. This definitely has recursion. But how to I determine the recurrence relation? Is this not the recurrence relation already? Also what is mean by "associated dimension space"?

Answer (score 2):

See section 6.5(Chain Matrix Multiplication) from http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap6.pdf

Here by associated dimension he means that the dimension of each matrix i.e M0 has dimensions d0, M1 has d1, M2 has d2 .... so on.